# Facebook Graph API not working with comments?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I created a page and an app with a Facebook Developer account.

In the Explorer Tool, I can retrieve a list of posts with this query without any issues:

```
104801368572889/feed?fields=message,attachments&access_token=[token]
```

However, not so lucky when I try to retrieve the comments associated to a post with this query:

```
104801368572889_105680201818339/comments?access_token=[token]
```

That's the error I get:

```
{
  "error": {
   "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 200,
   "fbtrace_id": "AOmx5mNZC9xUFysAWp4oX3s"
  }
}
```

It sounds like this means I don't have permissions. I tried to add all the possible permissions in the Explorer Tool (included the pages_read_engagement that is probably the one required for this API call). However, this doesn't seem to work. I also tried to add permissions in the app from the Developer Dashboard, but this brings me into a long process of information requests and reviews by Facebook. I don't want to go through this process as I'm just doing development at the moment. Isn't there something as a sandbox or development mode, where I can set the permissions that I want?

Comment: same here, @user1883212 did you find any solution?

Comment: The problem for me was that the explorer tool drop down slide back to user token even when selecting page token. And any token you set in the url is ignored as well as it will be overriden with the one generated in Explorer tool. It worked for me using postman...